# C# windows service to run taskkill.exe

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, windows-services, taskkill

I have C# service that uses FileSystemWatcher and invokes associated commands (e.g. batch files). One of the batch files needs to kill a running program, copy some files and start the program again. Taskkill is used to get rid of the program.

The batch file gets called, but taskkill command never kills a process (e.g. notepad.exe that a user has open). The same batch file works if i just run it when im logged in as that user.

I tried running the service as the logged on user account (the same one that has notepad open) to no avail - the default is Local System.

I can't hardcode the username (i am thinking, however, of configuration for impersonation but a bit reluctant to store the users' passwords).

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you debug to see what you are getting? is it throwing some error/exception ?

Comment: Can't say, runs as a local system. I tried piping the output like so: taskkill /IM notepad.exe > C:\Users\user\Desktop\testoutput.txt - the file is created but it's empty. If i run the command by double clicking the batch file, the following output is produced:
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "notepad.exe" with PID XXXX. - for each of the running notepads.

Comment: I don't think a failure in a batch script will throw an exception.

Comment: can you make sure you are running as administrator?

Comment: @Microtechie, sure does - tried both the ProcessStartInfo.Verb "runas" and adding the manifest to the service demanding admin. The solution is in my answer - apparently, need to /F on the taskkill. I couldn't find much on the topic initially which is why i decided not to delete the question after all.

Comment: Sure make sense , as it will Forces deletion of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running as local service always has the highest privilege, try taskkill /f to force terminate it. however, if still fail, check the error code by %errorlevel%

Comment: yeah figured that out a few minutes ago - had to /F to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it is worth deleting, perhaps not.
The local system was able to kill the process with the /F (force) switch on the taskkill.exe